# PHP: Time/HH:Minute:Seconds convert to Seconds

Tags: php

I have a code where it will subtract the `Total Duration` and the `Total Time`, and after that the result for the computation will be converted into seconds...

Assuming in my `Total Duration` is "02:00:00"
then for `Total Time` is "01:30:00"

For computation...

```
02:00:00 - 01:30:00 = 00:30:00
```

then for the result, "00:30:00" will be converted to seconds and the result is "1800"

How can I convert it?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: If you're using PHP date/time functions to do your existing computation, you should already have the answer in seconds... perhaps if you showed your code, we could point it out to you

Comment: But a duration of 00:30:00 isn't 30 seconds, it's 30 minutes or 1800 seconds

Comment: @MarkBaker..oh yeh..im sorry..will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** function. It returns the UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since January 1st 1970 00:00:00). If you'll pass the hour format `HH:MM:SS` to it, you can easily do the math

```
$to = strtotime('02:00:00');
$from = strtotime('01:30:00');

$seconds = $to - $from; // outputs 30
```

You assumed that the format is `minutes:seconds:miliseconds` and you wanted to receive 30 **seconds** in your case. Actually the output is 30 **minutes**. Miliseconds are separated with a dot.
Your hours should probably look like this:

```
$to = strtotime('00:02:00');
$from = strtotime('00:01:30');
```

Comment: @Matewka...hahah sorry wrong type...the result should be 1800...although I already edit it..thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

If you use format `HH:MM:SS` then you can convert it to seconds by next code

```
$timestr = "00:30:00";
$temp = explode(":", $timestr);
if ($temp && is_array($temp) && count($temp) == 3) {
  $time = intval($temp[0]) * 3600 + intval($temp[1]) * 60 + intval($temp[1]);
} else {
  $time = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting the Time-String into three substrings with the function (returns an array of substrings)

```
$substrings = new Array();
$substrings = explode(":", $timeString);
```

Now the array $substrings contains three substrings (hours, minutes, seconds). 
you could compute the seconds just by multiplicating:

```
$hours = intval($substrings[0]);
$minutes = intval($substrings[1]);
$seconds = intval($substrings[2]);
$seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    $start = '01:30:00';
    $end  = '02:00:00';
    $workingHours = (strtotime($end) - strtotime($start));
    $res= date("i", $workingHours); 
    echo "DIFF: ". $res; //OP 30 Minutes

    echo  $resFull= date("H:i:s", $workingHours); //OP 00:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with PHP 5.3:

```
<?php

try {
    $date1 = new DateTime('02:00:00');
    $date2 = new DateTime('01:30:00');

    $diff = $date1->diff($date2);

    echo $diff->format('H:i:s');


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
```